BizTalk wcf-sql receive location polling issues
We have a wcf-sql receive location in BizTalk 2020  which executes a stored procedure and brings back the results. Everything was working fine initially but suddenly the receive location is polling every minute ignoring the pollinginterval which is set for every 5 hours.
We also have a schedule setup for the receivelocation to run. But its is running out of the schedule sometimes now
We are executing a sp in the pollingstatement and the ambienttransaction property is set to false

Do you also have the Poll While data is found set to True?   I think there is an issue if you have Ambient Transactions off, but poll while data found on.

Poll while data found is set to false

So what changed in your environment?  Behavior like that doesn't usually change on its own.

No changes have been made.It suddenly started behaving so

Something must have changed, it wouldn't suddenly behave differently.  Was there patching on either the BizTalk server or DB server?

no patching has been made.

KB5003153 - FIX: Scheduled receive location polling outside service window. I have seen this KB article and fix can be done through Cumulative Update 2 for BizTalk 2020.Can you please suggest if this works in our case

What version of BizTalk are you on, and what CU is installed?  If it is BizTalk 2020 and you haven't installed CU2 or higher, then yes, you should be installing CU5 (which includes the fixes from CU2).
